# Обновление ключа postgresql поля json

Tags: json, postgresql, update

Добрый день. Есть в таблице, назовем её test, поле data, с данными в формате json. Данные для примера такие

{"key-1": "val-1", "key-2": "val-2"}

Вопрос такой, как написать запрос чтобы обновить именно ключи key-ххх?

Делаю такой запрос

UPDATE test SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{key-1}', '"key-999"', true)

обновляется не ключь, а значение у данного ключа т.е. val-1. И это понятно.

Нашел такой вариант

UPDATE test SET data = replace(data::TEXT, '"key-1" :','"key-999"')::jsonb

Вроде как сначала превращаем все в строку, делаем замену и возвращаем все обратно. И все по логике должно работать. Так и есть отрабатывает и говорит в логах, что все у тебя стало замечательно, но данные не поменялись. Ключ как был старым, так им и остался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался. Достаточно немного применить такую штуку, как внимательность. Ведь если мы превращаем все в строку, то и действовать нужно с данными, как со строкой.

не

UPDATE test SET data = replace(data::TEXT, '"key-1" :','"key-999"')::jsonb

а

UPDATE test SET data = replace(data::TEXT, '"key-1" :','"key-999":')::jsonb